# nginx keeps saying "welcome to nginx" even when nginx.conf changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, capistrano, vps

This is my nginx.conf, afetr succesfully deploying with capistrano:

```
http{
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    passenger_enabled on;
    root /home/gwuix2/picurwebaruhaz/releases/20130322133124/public/;
  }
}
```

I also added

```
gem 'capistrano-nginx'
```

to my Gemfile.rb

Nothings helps, the default nginx page keeps showing on.
Server:
Ubuntu VPS 12.10
i followed this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu

Comment: what does the nginx error log say ?

Comment: Have you checked this page? http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Config_Changes_Not_Reflected

Comment: When you say "deployed", do you mean to a production server? If so, did you change the "server_name"? In my case (nginx 1.4.1, reverse proxy to a node app), I had to change `server_name mysite.com` to `server_name www.mysite.com` or  `server_name *.mysite.com`.

Comment: Note: `mysite.com` here is just an example here. It would have to be changed to whatever your site's domain is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if sites-enabled and sites-available have an effect.  Try these links  [/running-rails-applications-using-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu-server](http://www.ivankuznetsov.com/2010/05/running-rails-applications-using-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu-server.html) and [configuring-nginx-and-phusion-passenger](http://blog.binarybalance.com.au/2010/09/19/configuring-nginx-and-phusion-passenger)

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart Nginx after modifying nginx.conf?

Comment: yes I did, like 10 times

Comment: alse did it with stop/start, but nothing helps

Comment: Clear your browser cache. This might help.

Comment: I wish the answer could be this easy

Comment: @RailsBeginner, how you finally solved the issue ?